# Does PRO satisfy binding condition A?

Tags: syntax, english, binding-theory

My assignment requires me to analyze two sentences (* denoting ungrammaticality):

*David realized that they have been spreading lies about himself

David has tended to spread lies about himself

The first one is ungrammatical because it violates condition A of the binding conditions: that a reflexive must be bound within its binding domain. The second sentence should be ungrammatical ad well, but it isn't. Is it because PRO (which is inserted because tended is a command verb not a raising one) is able to bind the reflexive? The whole phrase is responsible for binding, right? Not just the head?